# Data about country classifications / groups (advanced, emerging, developing economies)

Tags: data-request, imf

I am looking for a data about country classifications, I would need three categories:
**advanced economies; emerging market economies; developing economies**.

The IMF groups emerging and developing countries together (at least I don't find a different grouping) : https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2022/02/weodata/groups.htm

The world bank offers classifications into income groups which is already good but not quite what I need.
https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/906519

Another thing is that my data includes a lot of countries:
Would of course be nice too match the according group for as many countries as possible.
[image]

The preferred source is a known organization: IMF, UNO, Worldbank, etc..

So if you have any suggestions I would be really glad!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific time series you need?

Also, why not group them by GDP/capita? If this were *my* problem, and no suitable alternative existed, I would simply break them into... treciles, if that's the term. I'm not at my computer so unfortunately I can't show Stata code, but that may be one way of doing it. Assuming, that is, no other viable alternative exists.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response! Yes well there are ways to classify them by income, the GNI is used by the world bank, but that is not really what I am looking for.  Except there is a definition to classify countries into advanced, emerging, developing by GDP or GNI... 

And the country classifications don't have to be time series data. The most recent classification would already be very helpful.